# What to do with this Araucaria sprout

Tags: species-identification, botany, ecology, growth

I live in Santiago, Chile, and I see this Araucaria frequently:

[image]

For what I have read, it seems to be a female A. angustifolia individual (leaves are 2-3 cm long and a few mm wide, with a very sharp point; it gives round-ish cones with nuts, about 15 cm in diameter). **Am I right?**

Two days ago I found a nut in the ground, which I took without thinking about it too much. It was laying superficially and it took me no effort. Only when I had it in my hand I realized that it was a sprout, and become interested in knowing more.

[image]

Only then I learned Araucarias reproduced sexually, and understood the unlikeliness of my finding. It is possible that the sprout is A. angustifolia x A. araucana, since there are individuals of both species in the vicinity. (not very close, though!)

Considering the IUCN status of both species, I'm interested in raising it. I put it in a pot.

**Q: How can I identify the child? Can I save it? How should I care for it? (especially, watering, temperature, lighting, and the like)**